# How do I get out of this E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: package-management, kali-linux

I'm a beginner to linux.
I keep getting this error each time i try to install(`apt-get install` something..) or if I run (`sudo apt-get update` or `sudo apt-get upgrade`).

```
root@NOC:/home/samwel# sudo apt install apt-transport-https curl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-transport-https is already the newest version (2.1.10).
curl is already the newest version (7.72.0-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libgtksourceview2.0-0 libgtksourceview2.0-common
  linux-image-5.5.0-kali2-686-pae python-cairo python-chardet python-dbus
  python-enchant python-gi python-gobject-2 python-gtk2 python-gtksourceview2
  python-numpy python-pkg-resources python3-flask-restless python3-grequests
  python3-mimeparse python3-mimerender qemu-system-gui
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 35 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up kali-menu (2020.3.2) ...
update-kali-menu: error: can't open /usr/share/applications/libreoffice6.4-base.desktop: No such file or directory
dpkg: error processing package kali-menu (--configure):
 installed kali-menu package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-desktop-core:
 kali-desktop-core depends on kali-menu; however:
  Package kali-menu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package kali-desktop-core (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 kali-menu
 kali-desktop-core
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@NOC:/home/samwel#
```

Comment: If you are new to Gnu/Linux, then kari is not for you (tell your teacher). You need to learn on something that is easier and more stable. Most of the tools that kali gives you are available on Debian and other distros.

Answer (score 0):

Extract from error message. It looks to be the relevant part.

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of kali-desktop-core:
 kali-desktop-core depends on kali-menu; however:
  Package kali-menu is not configured yet.
```